# c++ word count(as words we take every possible variable name)

Tags: c++

I was asked to make a program that reads a cin could be text and then counts the words in it(i need to count as a word every name that can be accepted as a variable name ex _a,a1) my problem is that my code works for only one byte. if its more than one the sum is always 0.The only thing i think i can have wrong is that i didn't put the string into an array but a friend of mine told me i don't need to do so.below is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int sum=0;
    bool z= false;  //z is just a switch to see if we are inside a word\n
    string s;
    cout<<"Insert text: ";
    getline(cin,s);         //here we get the string\n
    int n=s.length()-1;     //for some reason i==(s.length-1) put a warning$
    for(int i=0;i==n;i++){  //here we check each byte to see what it contai$
            cout<<s[i];
            if(isalpha(s[i]) || s[i]=='_'){ //to enter a word we need a let$
                    z=true;
                    sum++;}
            if(z==true){    // if we are in a word we can have numbers as w$
                    if(!isalnum(s[i]) && s[i]!='_'){
                            z=false;}}      // exit the current word and go$
            if(s[i]==EOF){                  // the end\n
                    break;}}
    cout<<"Number of words is: "<<sum<<endl;        // the real end\n
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? What happens when you step into your for loop if `n > 0`?

Answer (score 1):

This is so much easier than the code you have provided. We can do this with the STL using an istream iterator. If you choose to use C++ and not C, then you should take advantage of the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main(){

   vector<string> words((istream_iterator<string>(cin)), istream_iterator<string>());

   for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) 
     cout << words[i] << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: LOL at the anonymous down-voter, who obviously is to afraid to state their reason for it. How does it feel to be a coward?

Comment: Your opinion is invalid.

Comment: does this count the weird names like a3a or _a?

Answer (score -1):

Check your for loop.. it runs as long as the second statement is true.. when is it true that i==n? only at the very last byte.. change this to i<=n instead.

Answer (score -3):

First of all you don't need dont use getline because it is insecure, use cin instead. Also you do not need the  and use cin instead of getline. Also if getline is used with an array it could pose a serious problem and could be exploited via stack overflow. Sorry I cant help much what you were asking but I just wanted to give you a heads up.